# Make + someone + something

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to say?

> Can you make me some tea?

or

> Can you fry me some eggs?

I already know about "**Can you make some tea for me?**" etc variation.

Answer (score 1):

This construction is using an **indirect object** and verbs that allow indirect objects are called **[ditransitive verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)**.  The indirect object always follows the verb and precedes the direct object.  The direct object is the thing that the verb *acts on*, and the indirect object is the person (or thing, but usually a person) the verb is *acting to or for*.

For example:

> I sent Mary an email.

In this sentence, "an email" is the direct object (the thing I sent) and "Mary" is the indirect object (the person the thing was sent to).

Common ditransitive verbs in English include *give, send, lend, lease, rent, hire, sell, write, tell, buy* and *make*.

Because **make** is ditransitive, it is indeed acceptable to say, "Can you make me some tea,"  where "some tea" is the direct object (the thing that will be made) and "me" is the indirect object (the person the thing will be made for).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These are both acceptable and very common phrasing for this type of quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you make me some tea?

This sentence is a very colloquial one. Native speakers do use it a lot. Though I am no native speaker, even I use it just as much as my next door neighbour.

> “You could wait until tomorrow,” he explained. “I could make you something to eat.” [Source article](https://www.vice.com/en/article/4wqpdd/shivas-wedding-0003000-v19n10)

As said in the above sentence (which is a response to a question similar to yours) are wisely used.

Also a more reliable search could be found on Google books like:

> "Would you make me some tea?" Annett asked. "Somehow I can't get warm. I always feel shivery in your flat." [Source of the sentence](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Who_Can_Make_Me_Happy/OZfLDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22make%20me%20some%20tea%22&pg=PT37&printsec=frontcover)

> "I do too. I'm thirsty. Can you make me some tea?" I ask, touching my neck and praying she falls for it. [Source of the sentence](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Make_Me_Yours/LK3qDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22make%20me%20some%20tea%22&pg=PT1115&printsec=frontcover)

*...and many more.*

[Google Ngram shows more frequency of "make me some tea" as compared to "make some tea for me"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20me%20some%20tea%2Cmake%20some%20tea%20for%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20me%20some%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20some%20tea%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmake%20me%20some%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20some%20tea%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0). But I must say, both sentences are idiomatic and perfectly grammatical as well.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your answers and comments

Comment: Thank you all guys for your answers and comments. Somehow I couldn't find a proper example in google search so I decided to ask. Anyways, you were all very helpful. Thanks again!